# Android Studio issue: Could not find com.google.android:cameraview:1.0.0

Tags: android

I keep facing this issue.

I tried

**1)**
./gradlew clean -> npm i -> expo i

**2)** add this line to build.graddle(:app)

> ```
>     multiDexEnabled true
> ```

**3)** add this line to build.graddle(project)

```
    maven {
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven"
    }
```

But nothing works.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.android:cameraview:1.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/Users/hayat/.m2/repository/com/google/android/cameraview/1.0.0/cameraview-1.0.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/cameraview/1.0.0/cameraview-1.0.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/android/cameraview/1.0.0/cameraview-1.0.0.pom
       - https://devrepo.kakao.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/google/android/cameraview/1.0.0/cameraview-1.0.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :expo > project :expo-camera
   > Could not find com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:1.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/Users/hayat/.m2/repository/com/github/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper/1.1.1/Android-Image-Cropper-1.1.1.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper/1.1.1/Android-Image-Cropper-1.1.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper/1.1.1/Android-Image-Cropper-1.1.1.pom
       - https://devrepo.kakao.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/github/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper/1.1.1/Android-Image-Cropper-1.1.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :expo > project :expo-image-picker

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

How to resolve this issue? please help me.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? Been encountering the same issue

Answer (score 12):

Encountered the same issue and solved it by adding the following code block to my `android\build.gradle` file.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // * Your other repositories here *
        maven {
            // expo-camera bundles a custom com.google.android:cameraview
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven"
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE** I believe the instructions given [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/sdk-47/packages/expo-camera) are kinda misleading. You must add the whole code block. I was only adding the code block below to no success. It's only after adding the whole block above that I was able to successfully build my project

```
maven {
            // expo-camera bundles a custom com.google.android:cameraview
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven"
        }
```

Comment: I felt into that one described in your notes. I added the maven block to the current definition and not added the entire allprojects block. I fixed it and worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
   maven(
       url( new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('expo-camera/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../android/maven") )
    )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCc4Q.png)